# How to check that a file is a Device?

Tags: php

***** This has been solved, [see my post containing the code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77339308/21885072).

---

I am making a CLI utility using PHP that will run on Windows and Linux, and I need to check whether a specified file is a device file.

I've had a look at [How to guarantee a specified file is a device on BSD/Linux from PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31631066/how-to-guarantee-a-specified-file-is-a-device-on-bsd-linux-from-php) but none of the approaches worked on multiple OSes.

How to approach this in a functional way?

---

On Linux `stat()` works on most files, but I don't know how to differentiate device vs regular files.

Running `stat("con")` on Windows returns an error whereas `stat("nul")` does not.

Comment: Hmmmm, `CON` and `NUL` are provided by the shell, yeah?  A solution might be specific to what shell you're running on under Windows... might have to just be hardcoded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if this is portable to Windows, but on Unix the file type is in octal digits 5-6 (from the right) of the `mode` element returned by [`stat()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.stat.php).

```
$stat = stat("filename");
$type = $stat[2] & 0770000;
$is_device = $type == 0060000 || $type == 0020000;
```

`0060000`  is a block device, `0020000` is a character device.

See the above documentation for the list of all file type values.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to [@Barmar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1491895/barmar) for his contribution, because of it I made this helper function that works on Windows and Linux which should make this process a lot easier.

### Source code

```php
function is_device(string $path): bool {
    $path = realpath($path);

    // Realpath returns false on non-existent files
    if ($path === false) {
        return false;
    }

    // Windows Reserved Filenames
    // Read: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365247%28VS.85%29.aspx
    $reserved = [
        "CON",   "PRN",  "AUX",  "NUL", "COM1",
        "COM2", "COM3", "COM4", "COM5", "COM6",
        "COM7", "COM8", "COM9", "LPT1", "LPT2",
        "LPT3", "LPT4", "LPT5", "LPT6", "LPT7",
        "LPT8", "LPT9"
    ];

    $uname = strtolower(php_uname());

    // @WARN: This may be mistaken for Darwin
    $is_windows = strpos($uname, "win") !== false;

    // On Windows we must check the basename of the file, if it matches
    // any of the reserved filenames specified above, it is considered
    // a device file.
    if ($is_windows) {
        $basename = strtoupper(explode('.', basename($path))[0]);

        // Name matches one of the reserved file names, return true
        if (in_array($basename, $reserved)) {
            return true;
        }
    }

    try {
        $stat = stat($path);
    } catch(Exception $e) {
        // We assume this is a device
        return true;
    }

    $type = $stat[2] & 0770000;
    $is_device = $type == 0060000 || $type == 0020000;

    return $is_device;
}
```

| Returns | When |
| --- | --- |
| true | a) File exists and is a device file, b) File name matches any of the reserved names on Windows, c) [*stat*](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.stat.php) fails. |
| false | a) Path points to a non-existent file, b) Not a device file. |

---

### Test cases

Windows:

```
C:\Boot               Is Device: 0
C:\Windows            Is Device: 0
C:\users              Is Device: 0
C:\Program Files      Is Device: 0
C:\nul                Is Device: 1
aux                   Is Device: 1
C:\Windows\prn        Is Device: 1
C:\users\aux          Is Device: 1
```

Linux:

```
/dev                  Is Device: 0
/var/log              Is Device: 0
/home/user            Is Device: 0
/root                 Is Device: 0
/dev/fb0              Is Device: 1
/dev/console          Is Device: 1
/dev/urandom          Is Device: 1
/dev/zero             Is Device: 1
```